# How to fix routing for Wireguard VPN Gateway

Tags: debian, iptables, routing, gateway, wireguard

I am desperately trying to get my Wireguard-VPN-Setup up and running as my Internet Connection has been switched to IPV6 (DS-lite).

**My Setup(raw):**

- NetCup VPS (acting as IPv4 contact point for my mobile devices out of the Internet)
- Internal Wireguard Server (acting as the Gateway between internal and
  external network)
- Iphone with Wireguard Client installed connected via mobile network only

**Current Status:**

- VPN Tunnel up and running between VPS and internal Wireguard Server as well as VPS and Mobile Client
- VPS (VPN Address 192.168.1.10) able to ping both peers (192.168.1.1 and 192.168.1.15)
- Internal Wireguard Server(192.168.1.1) able to ping VPS (192.168.1.10) but not able to reach Mobile Client (192.168.1.15) --> ICMP: Destination Host unreachable.
- tcpdump on VPS Server does not show any ICMP-Request coming in from my internal Wireguard Server when trying to ping 192.168.1.15
- Mobile Client (192.168.1.15) able to ping VPS (192.168.1.10) via VPN-Tunnel but not able to reach Internal Wireguard Server (192.168.1.1)

For me it seems to be a routing issue on the internal Gateway Server. Routes are set by wg-quick as follows:

default via 192.168.2.1 dev enp0s10 proto static metric 100
169.254.0.0/16 dev enp0s10 scope link metric 1000
192.168.1.0/24 dev wg0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.1
192.168.2.0/24 dev enp0s10 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.2.2 metric 100

IP-Forwarding is active.

Any Ideas on what I could have missed?

Any assistance is well appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure that ip forwarding is active for the wireguard interface?
Any firewall iptables/nftables rules involved?

Comment: Also please provide wireguard configuration for all machines involved. The routes on the other machines would also be useful, but assuming they are set up by wg-quick, you can leave those out.

Comment: Thanks for your quick replies! I found the solution in the meantime. I have added the details to the original posting.

Comment: You can answer your own question: it is better to keep the answer separate.

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux! I rolled back your recent edit tagging the title with "SOLVED".  If you have a solution, then consider adding that solution as a separate answer and accept it later. Accepting an answer will mark the question as resolved. Please see  https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution initially posted as an edit in the question.  Posted here (with grammatical fixes) as a community wiki answer as the original author did not do so themselves.

---

After another couple of hours of searching, I finally found a solution that did the trick for me.

The failed ICMP ping message (`192.168.1.1` to `192.168.1.15`) provided a key hint to find the solution. Besides stating that the destination was not reachable, it also stated:

```
sendmsg: Destination Address required
```

This message was provided by Wireguard.

The missing endpoint definition for the peer entries made for the two VPN clients in their corresponding `wg0.conf`-files was the source of this error.

Solution:

1. Removed the peer definitions for the clients initially meant to know each other directly. They don't work because the direct endpoints between VPN-Clients are not defined. This is where the ICMP message came from.
2. Added concrete peer addresses into the remaining peer definition which point to the Wireguard server, `192.168.1.10/32` for the server itself and `192.168.1.15/32` for the client (and vice versa for the other client).
3. Added a firewall rule to the `FORWARD` chain which allows packet forwarding between `wg0` as in and as outgoing device. In the first instance, I created specific traffic rules between the internal and VPN interface (in both directions). I'm not sure if this really had an effect.